# Returning a string entered as reverse text in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to make a method that returns a string of words in opposite order.

IE/ "The rain in Spain falls mostly on the"
    would return: "the on mostly falls Spain in rain The"

For this I am not supposed to use any built in Java classes just basic Java.

So far I have:

```
    lastSpace = stringIn.length(); 

    for (int i = stringIn.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        chIn = stringIn.charAt(i);
        if (chIn == ' '){
            word = stringIn.substring(i + 1, lastSpace);
            stringOut.concat(word);
            lastS = i;
        }
    }
    word = stringIn.substring(0,lastSpace);
    stringOut.concat(word);

    return stringOut;
```

My problem is when `stringOut` is returned to its caller it always is a blank string.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe my use of `string.concat()`?

Comment: What do you mean of you must using only built in java classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, Strings are immutable, i.e. they can't be changed. concat() returns a new string with the concatenation. So you want something like this:

```
stringOut = stringOut.concat(word);
```

or

```
stringOut += word
```

as Ray notes, there are more succinct ways to do this though.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String reverseWords(String words)
{
  if(words == null || words.isEmpty() || !words.contains(" "))
    return words;

  String reversed = "";
  for(String word : words.split(" "))
    reversed = word + " " + reversed;

  return reversed.trim();
}
```

Only API used is String (which should be allowed when manipulating Strings...)

Comment: Nice, but should be "return reversed.trim();" or add some rule for the first iteration since you added a whitespace character at the end there.

Answer (score 1):

You would do better if you use the indexOf method of String class, rather than that loop to find each space.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to assign the return of concat to something:

```
stringOut=stringOut.concat(word)
```

Strings in Java (and .net) are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseString(String originalString)
     {
     String reverseString="";
     String substring[]=originalString.split(" ");// at least one space between this double                      //quotes

    for(int i=(substring.length-1);i>=0;i--)
        {
        reverseString = reverseString + substring[i];
        }

      return sreverseString;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

I felt like coding , so here you go :

```
import java.util.*;

class ReverseBuffer {
    private StringBuilder soFar;
    public ReverseBuffer() {
        soFar = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void add(char ch) {
        soFar.append(ch);
    }

    public String getReversedString() {
        String str = soFar.toString();
        soFar.setLength(0);
        return str;
    }
}

public class Reverso {
    public static String[] getReversedWords(String sentence) {
        ArrayList < String > strings = new ArrayList < String >();
        ReverseBuffer rb = new ReverseBuffer();
        for(int i = 0;i < sentence.length();i++) {
            char current = sentence.charAt(i);
            if(current == ' ') {
                strings.add(rb.getReversedString());
            }
            else {
                rb.add(current);
            }
        }
        strings.add(rb.getReversedString());
        Collections.reverse(strings);
        return (String[])strings.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cSentence = "The rain in Spain falls mostly on the";
        String words[] = Reverso.getReversedWords(cSentence);
        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: had to call getReversedString once more after the loop.

Hope this helps !